# 'this' (inside method) doesn't refer back to original object?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have an object as so:

```
let game = {
    canvas: document.getElementById('main_canvas').getContext("2d"),
    clear: function(){
        this.canvas.clearRect(0,0,400,400);
    },
    update: function(){
        this.clear();
        //more code
    },
};
```

In my clear method everything works using 'this' referring to 'game', however when I use 'this' in the 'update' method it doesn't refer to 'game'? When i use game.clear(); everything works, but with 'this' i get undefined. If anyone know the reason for this please post a response. I have recently learned about objects and know that arrow functions don't give a 'this', but thought anonymous functions like the ones above would allow me to refer to the 'parent' or owner object.

Comment: The way you are using `this` is the way you should use it with constructor functions (when you make an instance of the object via invoking a function with `new`), not with static object literals.

Comment: The value of `this` depends on how a function is called. So show us how `game.update` is called. Likely a duplicate of [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/218196)

Comment: You should also read [How does the “this” keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/218196), https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this and https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes

Answer (score 0):

You need to use .bind

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

This essentially binds it to the object where the method is created.

it should look something like this.

```
let game = {
    canvas: document.getElementById('main_canvas').getContext("2d"),
    clear: function(){
        this.canvas.clearRect(0,0,400,400);
    }.bind(this),
    update: function(){
        this.clear();
        //more code
    }.bind(this),
};
```

Comment: Or do `game.update()`, which will work, rather than something like `callback = game.update; callback()`, which will not work.

Comment: And if there is ES6 support (as using a transpiler like babel) can use arrow function.

Comment: You might want to show how they'd apply `.bind` to their case.

Comment: @ChristianBenseler: Arrow functions will most likely not be a solution to the OP's problem. Arrow functions are primarily useful if you are trying to access `this` inside a callback inside a method. But here it seems the OP is simply calling `game.update` "incorrectly".

Comment: @FelixKling you are right. I made a mistake, I misinterpreted the code and thought that 'game' was already an instance of an object (such as 'game is instanceof Game').

Comment: Your example is incorrect. `this` in `.bind(this)` won't refer to `game`.